# IE9 Document Mode in a frameset frame

Tags: html, internet-explorer-9, frames, frameset, quirks-mode

I support an old, very large app with antiquated tabs, tree views, context menus, and a frameset.  It is laid out with navigation tabs and tree views in a left frame and a data entry frame on the right.  It is totally reliant on IE Quirks Mode.

This app is so big that a total rewrite in one hit is not feasible, so I have been investigating options for incremental updates.  The most obvious I thought was loading modern MVC/HTML5 etc screens in the right data entry frame.  I have had considerable success with this except that I cannot get the screens to run in IE9 Document Mode.  If I load the modern screens independent of the old frameset they run in IE9 Document Mode no problems, but when loaded in the frameset they drop back to IE8 Document Mode.  I have tried all sorts of meta tag and http header directives with no luck.  This is not necessarily a show-stopper but is there any way to solve this?  I thought it might be related to frames being obsolete in HTML5?

Thanks!

Comment: Your last sentence answers your question, `frameset`s and `frame`s really are obsoleted in HTML5, thus they cant be shown in IE9 Standards mode.

Answer (score 0):

> Your last sentence answers your question, framesets and frames really are obsoleted in HTML5, thus they cant be shown in IE9 Standards mode.